# Why cant I view objects in render mode?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I am new to blender and i am following a tutorial series. For some reason I am not able to view the platform in my rendered image or in render mode. I am able to view them in material preview and other modes. I even duplicated the platform for making the wall and that too isn't visible.
This is in material preview.

[image]

This is in render mode
[image]

Comment: if my answer doesn't work, please provide blend file

Answer (score 2):

Tap on filter in Outliner -> check camera icon.

[image]

Check now in outliner whether the camera icon on the right is checked. (it should be checked to show in render)

[image]